# PostgreSQL Inserting Null works using COPY but fails using INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.6

I have a bigint column named `mycolumn`. I execute SQL scripts using the PSQL command.

Using `COPY` command:

```
COPY public.mytable (myothercol, mycolumn) FROM stdin;
1   \N
\.
```

This works. But the following does not work:

```
EXECUTE 'insert into public.mytable (myothercol, mycolumn) values ($1,$2);' USING 
1,NULL;
```

This gives me error:

> column "mycolumn" is of type bigint but expression is of type text

Why does `insert` not work for null value, whereas `COPY` works?

Comment: Why the dynamic SQL to begin with? You could simply use `insert into public.mytable (myothercol, mycolumn) values ($1,$2);`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how do I give values of $1 $2 ?

Comment: Those are apparently parameters to your function, aren't they?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not using a function. Its a simple plpgsql script between DO END

Comment: Then use `insert into public.mytable (myothercol, mycolumn) values (1, null);`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using EXECUTE as I also have other columns which will have dynamic data

Comment: You can use PL/pgSQL variables in the `values()` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You best tell PostgreSQL to convert the parameter to `bigint` explicitly:

```
EXECUTE 'insert into public.mytable (myothercol, mycolumn) values ($1,$2::bigint);'
   USING 1,NULL;
```

The problem is that PostgreSQL does not automatically know what data type a NULL is, so it guesses `text`. `COPY` does not have to guess a data type.